# How to Sort a list of objects based on two date fields

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, sorting, collections

I am trying to sort a list of objects in Java. Each object contains two date fields `Date1` and `Date2`.
If `Date1` is not null then `Date2` should be null and if `Date2` is not null then `Date1` should be null. Let's say Our class name is `Product` and we have a list `inventoryList` of object `products`.

```
products :[
           {
             "name":"abc",
             ...,
             "Date1": "2021-04-18 10:36:34 PM",
             ..., 
             "Date2":"null",
             ...
           },
            "name":"def",
             ...,
             "Date1": "null",
             ...,
             "Date2":"2021-05-17 11:26:34 PM",
             ...
           ]
```

I want to sort this list with respect to either of the date of the object in descending order.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type are the Dates? `java.util.Date`, `java.time.LocalDate`, ...? I think you can use Streams with the `.sorted`-method to achieve this.

Comment: Well we are storing the dates in String format. I am able to sort the list using Streams using one date field, but unable to figure out how to implement sorting using both of the date  fields

Comment: *we are storing the dates in String format* Stop doing that. Are you also storing your numbers and your Boolean values as strings? Since your dates and times haven’t got time zone or UTC offset, use `LocalDateTime` for them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Comparator.comparing()` method to specify the property to sort in a lambda expression.

```
record Product(String name, LocalDate Date1, LocalDate Date2) {}

List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(
    new Product("abc", LocalDate.of(2021, 4, 18), null),
    new Product("def", null, LocalDate.of(2021, 5, 17)));

products.sort(Collections.reverseOrder(
    Comparator.comparing(p -> p.Date1() != null ? p.Date1() : p.Date2())));

products.stream()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

output:

```
Product[name=def, Date1=null, Date2=2021-05-17]
Product[name=abc, Date1=2021-04-18, Date2=null]
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can try using the below approach for sorting the data based on dates using stream.**

*Here, I have used dates in the LocalDateTime format instead of String.*

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Product p1 = new Product("abc", LocalDateTime.parse("2021-04-18 10:36:34 PM",formatter),null);
        Product p2 = new Product("def",null,LocalDateTime.parse("2021-05-17 11:26:34 PM",formatter));

        List<Product> sortedList = Stream.of(p1,p2)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getDate1()!=null ? x.getDate1():x.getDate2(),
                        Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.reverseOrder())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(sortedList);
    }
}
```

**Product.java**

```
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime date1;
    private LocalDateTime date2;

    public Product(String name, LocalDateTime date1, LocalDateTime date2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date1 = date1;
        this.date2 = date2;
    }
    
    //getters and setters
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Product{name='def', date1=null, date2=2021-05-17T23:26:34},
 Product{name='abc', date1=2021-04-18T10:36:34, date2=null}]
```

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks.. Yes you are right since the user input is also in AM/PM format, I have just modified the formatter with `hh` with `a` and along with `Locale.ENGLISH`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to handle the choosing date logic inside `Product` class like this

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Product {
    private String name;
    private Date dateOne;
    private Date dateTwo;

    public Product(String name, Date dateOne, Date dateTwo) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dateOne = dateOne;
        this.dateTwo = dateTwo;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        if (this.dateOne != null) {
            return dateOne;
        }
        return dateTwo;
    }

}
```

Then in the `Inventory` class you can sort like this

```
public class Inventory {
    public List<Product> sort(List<Product> products) {
        products.sort((Product productOne, Product productTwo) -> {
                if (productOne.getDate().before(productTwo.getDate())) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (productOne.getDate().after(productTwo.getDate())) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
        });

      return products;
    }
}
```

Comment: While storing date and time in a `String` was certainly no good idea, please don’t suggest the `Date` class. It was poorly designed and is fortunately long outdated, replaced nearly 10 years ago. We need `LocalDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Having the `Product` object itself find the non-null date and time is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`List.sort(Comparator<? super E>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) to sort a list in situ, providing a `Comparator` - an instruction of how two `Products` would've been compared:

```java
products.sort((x, y) -> {/* logics */})
```

And now you can compare on `x` and `y` i.e. get and compare their dates, do `null` checks, etc., and return an integer whose signum tells if `x` is greater or smaller in order than `y`.

Comment: While it can be made to work, it’s smarter to use `Comparator.comparing()` or one of the other static factory methods in the `Comparing` interface. You will still need to code some logic, but simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Streams, and you are not able to change the `Product`-class you can implement your own `Comparator` and use this in the Stream-logic.

Comparator-Example:

```java
public class ProductComparator implements Comparator<Product> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Product product1, Product product2) {
        String product1Date = product1.getDate1() != null ? product1.getDate1() : product1.getDate2();
        String product2Date = product2.getDate1() != null ? product2.getDate1() : product2.getDate2();

        return product1Date.compareTo(product2Date);
    }
}
```

The sorting with Streams could then look like this:

```java
List<Product> productListSorted = productList.stream()
                .sorted(new ProductComparator())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you just want to sort the list itself, you can use:

```java
productList.sort(new ProductComparator());
```

Be aware that this Comparator will throw a `NullPointerException` if both Dates are `null`.

Comment: `(p1, p2) -> new ProductComparator().compare(p1, p2)` may be just `new ProductComparator()`

Comment: Thx for the input @英語は苦手. Adapted my answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a collection with a custom comparator to sort. Inside the custom comparator, I checked for which date was not null and then returned the comparison.

```
class Product {
    private String name;
    private String date1;
    private String date2;
    
    public Product(String name, String date1, String date2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date1 = date1;
        this.date2 = date2;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getDate1() {
        return this.date1;
    }
    public String getDate2() {
        return this.date2;
    }
}

public class SortProductsByDate {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Product> inventoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        inventoryList.add(new Product("abc", "2021-04-18 10:36:34 PM", null));
        inventoryList.add(new Product("def", null, "2021-05-17 11:26:34 PM"));
        
        Collections.sort(inventoryList, new Comparator<Product>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Product p1, Product p2) {
                String d1 = p1.getDate1() == null ? p1.getDate2() : p1.getDate1();
                String d2 = p2.getDate1() == null ? p2.getDate2() : p2.getDate1();
                
                return d2.compareTo(d1);
            }
            });
        
        for(Product p : inventoryList) {
            System.out.printf("name: %s\nDate1: %s\nDate2: %s\n\n", p.getName(), p.getDate1(), p.getDate2());
        }
    }
}
```

Console Output:

```
name: def
Date1: null
Date2: 2021-05-17 11:26:34 PM

name: abc
Date1: 2021-04-18 10:36:34 PM
Date2: null
```

You can also separate the logic even further and clean up the main method. Implement the comparator within Product class and create a separate class for ProductInventory. Also keep in mind when you override compareTo() that you should also take care of equals() and hashcode() method as well to avoid any issues. I auto-generated those fields within the IDE.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

class Product implements Comparable<Product>{
    private String name;
    private String date1;
    private String date2;
    
    public Product(String name, String date1, String date2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date1 = date1;
        this.date2 = date2;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public String getDate1() {
        return this.date1;
    }
    
    public String getDate2() {
        return this.date2;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Product other) {
        String thisDate = this.getDate1() == null ? this.getDate2() : this.getDate1();
        String otherDate = other.getDate1() == null ? other.getDate2() : other.getDate1();
        return otherDate.compareTo(thisDate);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(date1, date2, name);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Product other = (Product) obj;
        return Objects.equals(date1, other.date1) 
                && Objects.equals(date2, other.date2)
                && Objects.equals(name, other.name);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String date = date1 == null ? date2 : date1;
        return "[name:" + name + ", date=" + date + "]";
    }
}

class ProductInventory {
    private List<Product> inventoryList;
    
    public ProductInventory() {
        this.inventoryList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    }
    
    public List<Product> getInventoryList() {
        return this.inventoryList;
    }
    
    public void add(Product p) {
        this.inventoryList.add(p);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Product p : inventoryList) {
            sb.append(p.toString());
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
public class SortProductsByDateDescending {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        ProductInventory productInventory = new ProductInventory();
        
        productInventory.add(new Product("abc", "2021-04-18 10:36:34 PM", null));
        productInventory.add(new Product("def", null, "2022-03-08 03:30:24 AM"));
        productInventory.add(new Product("ghi", null, "2021-05-17 11:26:34 PM"));
        productInventory.add(new Product("jkl", "2025-01-22 01:33:16 AM", null));
        productInventory.add(new Product("mno", "2025-01-22 01:33:16 PM", null));
        productInventory.add(new Product("pqr", "2025-01-22 01:33:17 PM", null));
        
        Collections.sort(productInventory.getInventoryList());
        System.out.println(productInventory.toString());
    }
}
```

Console Output:

```
[name:pqr, date=2025-01-22 01:33:17 PM]
[name:mno, date=2025-01-22 01:33:16 PM]
[name:jkl, date=2025-01-22 01:33:16 AM]
[name:def, date=2022-03-08 03:30:24 AM]
[name:ghi, date=2021-05-17 11:26:34 PM]
[name:abc, date=2021-04-18 10:36:34 PM]
```